# Intellij - Unable to use newer Java 8 classes - Error : "Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+.."

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

I'm trying to use a `java.lang.function.Function` in my java 8 code base, but i keep getting the following error in Intellij.

> Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+  This inspection finds all
>   usages of methods that have @since tag in their documentation.  This
>   may be useful when development is performed under newer SDK version as
>   the target platform for production

I seem to have the correct Project and Compiler settings

**Project Settings: (File -> Project Structure)**

```
Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK = Java 1.8
Project Settings -> Project -> Project Language Level = 8 - Lambdas, Type Annotations etc
```

**Compiler Settings: (File -> Settings)**

```
Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Project Bytecode Version : 1.8
Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Per module Bytecode Version -> Target Bytecode Version : 1.8
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Edited the answer based on Bastien Jansen comment.

Seems that there is another project setting that affects the compiler level. A subtle indication of this problem is when your compiler starts complaining of the source and target java version being different from the one you specified while you are compiling the code

```
Warning:java: source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
Warning:java: target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
Warning:java: To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
```

To get rid of this, you need to open up

`File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules -> "Your Module Name" -> Sources -> Language Level`

and change that to the desired level i.e 1.8 or the Project Default language level

Comment: This worked , but then I got "Error:java: javacTask: source release 8 requires target release 1.8", which I resolved by following the advice mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888592/errorjava-javactask-source-release-8-requires-target-release-1-8.

Comment: In Android-Studio 2.3.3, you need to go to each module in `File > Project Structure` and define the Source and Target compatibility

Comment: This project setting is overwritten when you do a re-import if you are using Maven. This happens every time you change the pom, and will quickly frustrate you having to keep your intellij settings up to date. For Maven projects, the below pom changes are more appropriate.

Comment: Absolutely mind-boggling that this is not the default when creating a new Maven project. I hate Java.

Comment: I had to do this when I changed the project sdk from java 8 to java 11, thanks a ton!

Comment: you have to change the compile version of java source and target in pom

Answer (score 57):

If you are using maven then Add below line in your configuration **pom.xml** file and then reimport or build it from maven.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Else** select java compiler and Language Level from below path.

File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules > your Module name > Sources > Language Level > choose the one which you need.

[image]

Change Language level from here :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Don't know why this isn't default. Even in 2019.1.3 which I'm using.

Answer (score 34):

Actually, if you are using Maven and your `pom.xml` project properties are configured correctly

```
<project xmlns="...> 
....
<properties>
         <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
         <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
...
</project
```

You can reimport Maven parameters to `intellij-idea` project - right click on project root entry, then `Maven -> Reimport` which is at the bottom.

[image: picture shows that Maven is second from last item in project right click menu]

Answer (score 33):

I just fixed it as follows:

Right click the project -> Open Module Settings -> Modules -> Sources -> 8 or higher

[image]

And then

[image]

If still encounter the error and using **maven**, you have to add the build configuration in your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Java Compiler

Change Target bytecode version to 1.8 of the module that you are working for.

If you are using Maven

Add the compiler plugin to pom.xml under the top-level project node:

```html
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is one other place that might be causing this issue, regardless of whether or not you are using Maven or Gradle.

In `Settings | Editor | Inspections | Java language level migration aids | Usages of API which isn't available at the configured language level`, the default (I believe) is set to `Respecting to project language level settings`, but it *can* be set to `Higher than:` , which ignores project settings.

Meaning that if you follow the instructions in the other answers and set your project's language level to, say, 8, but the inspection is set to `Higher than: 7`, IDEA will still throw a fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gradle, don't forget to make sure the following is set to 1.8 and not 1.5 (for instance for some bizarre reason in Intelij it defaults to 1.5) so no matter what you do at the project level to set the compiler compatibility level, this setting will cause it to continue giving you trouble with Java 8 features that it would not recognize:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your config of repository has properties include compiler Version. examine
`settings.xml` file.

```
<jdk>1.8</jdk>
</activation>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>1.8</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
</properties>
```