# How to use Java 8 Stream API under Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, api, anonymous-function

Just set up a project using Android Studio 2.2.3 with Java 1.8 and Android 7 (API Level 24) trying to test the "new" java 8 feature `Stream`.

Here my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.radinator.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here the code:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
public class MainActivity extens Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainactivity);
    }

    void foo(){
        List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");
        myList.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    }

}
```

Android Studio underlines the line `myList.stream()...` telling me "`Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+` " Gradle is compiling everything but why do I get this message? I thought this feature is introduced with Java 8 and available under Android API Leve 24 and above?

How can I solve this mess?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this could help (setting the module lang level): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787079/intellij-unable-to-use-newer-java-8-classes-error-usage-of-api-documented

Comment: if android studio had this option I'd changed it. sadly there is no such option (only compile sdk version and build tool version)

Comment: API Level 24 = Nougat, Android 7.0-7.1.1, API Level 23 = Marshmallow, Android 6.0(.1)

Comment: thanks for correcting me ;D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update** 2017-04-04

[Jack is deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html), Google is replacing it with something called *desugar*. It is now available with [Android Studio 2.4 preview 4](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-studio-24-preview-4-is-now.html) and later.

Java 8 language/library feature availability is still dependent on the device API level and Android Studio version so make sure to [double check what you can and can't use](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html#supported_features).

To use it you'd just set the source and target language levels to Java 8.

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Note that if you're already using retrolambda or jack, you will need to disable them for desugar to be used. You find more info on how to use it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html).

I have not yet tried it myself since I prefer IntelliJ IDEA and quick research into how to use it with IDEA wasn't fruitful. I will update this answer again once I figure out how to use it in IDEA.

**Old answer**

**Some** Java 8 language features are available when using Jack compiler.

to enable Jack, edit your `build.gradle` like so

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

However, I would like to add that I've had pretty bad experience with jack so far, especially when debugging. I would recommend using [streamsupport](https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport) and [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) instead <del>for now until jack's sister [Jill](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill) is released</del>.

Comment: Jack is being deprecated as of next month.

Comment: apparently, https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html ... well, retrolambda to the rescue... though there's still hope

Comment: I'll try to remember to update this answer once I've seen the new stuff