# Get differences between two arrayList but compare them in uppercase

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy

I have two arrayList and I need to compare them, get the values that are uniques and build a new array with them, problem is some of the values are the same but in uppercase so they shouldn't show as unique value. This is my code alredy, works but is to slow

```
for (i = 0; i < parsedLocal.size(); i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < parsedRemote.size(); j++) {
     if (parsedLocal[i].toUpperCase().equals(parsedRemote[j].toUpperCase())){ 
        parsedLocal.remove(parsedLocal[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Then I found this solution that is faster but doesn't compare uppercases or lowercases, any idea on how to do that with that method or similar?

```
parsedLocal.removeAll(parsedRemote);
```

Comment: Is it all uppercase or all lowercase?  Or are there also mixed cases?

Comment: Mixed cases, some of the values are writed like Jhon, jhon for example

Comment: You can convert all both the lists to uppercase or lowercase and then call 
    parsedLocal.removeAll(parsedRemote);

Comment: @S.K. is there a method to convert them in to uppercase or lowercase without iterating?

Comment: You will have to iterate. However streams are bit faster. strings.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList()); Also this will remove the nested loop which is way slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following groovy code should compute the difference (note that the returned collection will contain upper-case values):

```
parsedLocal*.toUpperCase() - parsedRemote*.toUpperCase()
```

But you can also use a stream-based computation. This has a slightly higher space complexity, but should have linear time complexity:

```
Set<String> set1 = parsedLocal.stream()
        .map{it.toUpperCase()}
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<String> retained = parsedRemote.stream()
        .filter{!set1.contains(it.toUpperCase())}
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) can be easy in java 8 as follows:

```
    List<String> parsedLocal = new ArrayList();
    parsedLocal.add("aa");
    parsedLocal.add("bb");
    List<String> parsedRemote = new ArrayList();
    parsedRemote.add("AA");
    List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>(parsedLocal);
    for (String s : parsedRemote) {
        tmpList.removeIf((t) -> t.equalsIgnoreCase(s));
    }
    System.out.println(tmpList);
```

And the output:

```
[bb]
```

Comment: tryed that, getting an error on tmpList.removeIf line

startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 8: unexpected token: -> @ line 8, column 30.
           tmpList.removeIf((t) -> t.equalsIgnoreCase(s));
                                ^

1 error

Comment: lambda not supported? not using java 8?

Comment: @CristianGonzalez You should tag your question with `groovy` if this is not java code.

Comment: @Hearen openjdk version "1.8.0_111"

Comment: @CristianGonzalez Would you please locally tested it using terminal run javac and java?

Comment: If you are using some IDE, you need to make sure the language level is correct. something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787079/intellij-unable-to-use-newer-java-8-classes-error-usage-of-api-documented/51372953#51372953

Comment: @Hearen The problem is that the code is compiled as groovy code. And surely the version of groovy being used doesn't support the java lambda syntax.