# How do I solve usage of API documented as @since 1.8+ error...on Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing with `Android Studio 2.2 RC 2`.

In my app I am getting the error message:

```
    Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+ less... (Ctrl+F1) 
    This inspection finds all usages of methods that have @since tag in their documentation.  
This may be useful when development is performed under newer SDK version as the target platform for production.
```

I did some research to try solve the problem, the first link I found is:

[Intellij - Unable to use newer Java 8 classes - Error : "Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787079/intellij-unable-to-use-newer-java-8-classes-error-usage-of-api-documented)

It says to get rid of the error, you need to open up

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules -> "Your Module Name" -> Sources -> Language Level
```

and change that to the desired level i.e 1.8 or the Project Default language level.

In `Android Studio 2.2 RC 2` I see `File -> Project Structure`... and then the other headings/tabs are different to the one listed in the solution of above link. And other solutions elsewhere say to do the same thing...Is there another way of getting rid of this error, in `Android Studio 2.2 RC 2`?

Regards,

C.